# j_spring_security_logout doesn't configures logout-success-url

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I want to manually redirect logOut of spring and need to save the date if the user logOuts 
But I cannot redirect it.

My spring-security.xml goes like:

```
<security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/login?logout=1" delete-  cookies="JSESSIONID"/>
```

My jsp page:

```
  <spring:url var="logoutUrl" value="/j_spring_security_logout" />
        <li><a id="button" href="${logoutUrl}">Logout</a></li>
```

Then i wanted to check the logout parameter like:

```
  RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getLoginForm(@ModelAttribute("user") User user, Model      model,@RequestParam(value = "logout", required = false) String logout)
 {
    {
        try {
            log.info("Opening Login page");
            model.addAttribute("org.springframework.validation.BindingResult.user", model.asMap().get("addUserForm"));
            ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
           if (logout != null) {//logout is always null
               //save date 
               modelAndView.addObject("msg", "You've been logged out successfully.");  

               }
            } catch (Exception er) {
            log.error("Error in opening Login page" + er);
        }
        return "/login";
    }
```

Comment: What's the real problem. What are you expecting and what happens differently?

Comment: logout-success-url is not working. i want to check the logout parameter to know if the user log out and save the date .But the page is never redirected to the logout-success-url.  I am expecting /j_spring_security_logout to configure the logout-success-url and the page to redirect to /login?logout=1. But it is not working.